# JavaScript область видимости переменных. Как работает код?

Tags: javascript

Не могу понять почему не перезаписывается значение у глобальной переменной. Объясните пожалуйста подробно, как вообще работает скрипт.

```js
var title = "external title";

function example(){
  title = "changing external title";
  console.log(title);
  var title = "internal title";
}

example(); // "changing external title"
console.log(title); // "external title"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`var` [всплывает](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5). Поэтому title внутри функции - это не external title.

Comment: то есть, var title = "internal title"; становится в начало тела функции?

Comment: Не совсем. `var title` - всплывает в начало. А `title  = "internal title";`  остается там где есть.

Comment: var title - всплывает при инициализации, да?

Comment: @Ikar копипаст: JavaScript "поднимает" только объявление, но не инициализацию.

Comment: если закомментировать строчку title = "changing external title"; то код выведет undefined и external title. Следовательно ничего не всплывает.

Comment: @Ikar переменная объявлена, но не инициализирована. Если бы она не была объявлена - вы бы получили не undefined, а эксепшн `Uncaught ReferenceError: title is not defined`. (Если бы она при этом и в глобальной области видимости тоже не была бы объявлена, разумеется)